# Hide line from Plotly.js chart

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

Having the legend removed from a plotly chart, is it still possible to hide any line by e.g. clicking on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in feature for this, but you could add an event listener that calls `restyle()` and sets `visible=false` on the trace. Note, however, that if you do this, without a legend present there wouldn't be anything for the user to click on to make the trace visible again!